# Arduino String comparison not working

Tags: c++, c, arduino, strcmp

I tried to compare a EEPROM stored SSID that returns a string to the `WiFi.SSID()` function.

Although it is literally the same in the Serial Monitor I don't get a match and it never reaches the `if` statement.

I tried using `==` operator without the `.str()` and used `if( strcmp ( a.c_str(),b.c_str)==1)`

Nothing seems to work. What am I missing here?

```
void ConnectToBestWifi()
{
  int apnos = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  int loc[3];
  int no=0;
  for(int i=0;i<apnos;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("Wifi SSID");
      Serial.println(WiFi.SSID(i).c_str());
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("Read SSID");
      Serial.println(ReadWifiSSID(j).c_str());
      Serial.println("");

    if (strcmp(((WiFi.SSID(i)).c_str()),((ReadWifiSSID(j)).c_str()))==1)
    {
      Serial.println("gotcha");
      loc [no]=i;
      no++;        
    }
  }
```

Image of Serial Monitor attached below

[image: Serial Monitor]

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp), **once again**.

Also, quoting `C11`, chapter §7.24.4.2 , (*emphasis mine*)

> ```
> int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```
>
> The `strcmp` function returns an integer greater than, **equal to**, or less than **zero**,
>   accordingly **as the string pointed to by `s1` is** greater than, **equal to**, or less than **the string pointed to by `s2`**.

`strcmp()` returns a `0` when both the strings match. So,

```
 if (strcmp(((WiFi.SSID(i)).c_str()),((ReadWifiSSID(j)).c_str()))==1)
```

should better be

```
 if (strcmp (((WiFi.SSID(i)).c_str()),((ReadWifiSSID(j)).c_str())) == 0)
```

Comment: I would also remove useless extra parenthesis: `if(strcmp(WiFi.SSID(i).c_str(), ReadWifiSSID(j).c_str()) == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

As already said, you are using `strcmp` wrong.

But you don't need to use that.
You can compare `String` objects directly with `==`.

```
if (WiFi.SSID(i) == ReadWifiSSID(j))
```

Comment: much more readable; let the compiler do the work! (this is actually as fast on arduino)